# Flutter Blue characteristic length is limited

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, characteristics

I am developing an app in flutter using flutter blue plugin where i am getting the data from a customized bluetooth low energy controller all the neccessary data is in characteristic of the property of notify listner. when i listen the data its 16 bytes evertime but some sensors have data more than 16 bytes so its breaks the array into multiple arrays one array at a time. like

```
 [187(start), 17, 8, 132, 86, 34, 146, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
  [4, 255, 255, 143, 204(end-checksum), 187(start again), 17, 8, 168, 77, 34, 146, 114, 0, 19, 1]
 [251, 0, 235, 70, 65, 5, 0, 0, 169, 204]
```

i tried to request with larger mtu with status 0 like

```
widget.device.requestMtu(512);
```

Controller's maximum mtu size is 247 bytes but by default its showing 20 bytes.

but it gives the same result but i want to get array from 187 to 204 everytime when characteristic listner is called with no broken arrays.and data is not limited its keep updating.
console :

```
I/flutter (  505): full value [187, 12, 9, 100, 90, 80, 70, 40, 1, 251, 
8, 16, 24, 85, 6, 204]
  I/flutter (  505): full value [187, 5, 16, 15, 58, 92, 100, 25, 204]
  I/flutter (  505): full value [187, 7, 25, 1, 14, 20, 10, 0, 0, 70, 
 204]
 I/flutter (  505): full value [187, 6, 26, 5, 3, 5, 0, 0, 39, 204]
  I/flutter (  505): full value [187, 10, 27, 1, 10, 15, 50, 55, 80, 85, 
130, 
 135, 76, 204]
  I/flutter (  505): full value [187, 17, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 253, 0, 19, 1, 
 251, 
  0, 233, 74, 16]
I/flutter (  505): full value [0, 0, 0, 87, 204, 187, 13, 1, 84, 77, 85, 
 95, 
84, 69, 83, 84]
```

code i tried :

```
     await widget.device.requestMtu(512);
     await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
     final mtu=await widget.device.mtu.first;
     print(mtu);
     List<BluetoothService> servicevalue = await widget.device
        .discoverServices();

     print("sssssssssssss+${servicevalue}");
    for (BluetoothService service in servicevalue) {
      for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in service.characteristics) {
        if (c.uuid.toString() == "6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9- 
      e50e24dcca9e") {
          print("cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc+${c}");


          c.value.listen((value) {
            print("full value ${value}");
            if (value.isNotEmpty) {
              ////////////////////////////////Door///////////////////////////////////
              if (value?.elementAt(0) == 187 &&
                  value?.elementAt(2) == 9 &&
                  value?.elementAt(8) == 1) {
                setState(() {  doortext = "OPEN";
                doorcolor = Colors.redAccent;});

              }
              if (value?.elementAt(0) == 187 &&
                  value?.elementAt(2) == 9 &&
                  value?.elementAt(8) == 0) {
                setState(() {
                  doortext = "CLOSED";
                  doorcolor = Colors.green;
                });
              }
              ///////////////////////BRAKE////////////////////////////////////////
              if (value?.elementAt(0) == 187 &&
                  value?.elementAt(2) == 27 &&
                  value?.elementAt(3) == 0) {
                setState(() {
                  pbrake = "RELEASED";
                  brakecolor = Colors.black;
                });
              }
              if (value?.elementAt(0) == 187 &&
                  value?.elementAt(2) == 27 &&
                  value?.elementAt(3) == 1) {
                setState(() {
                  pbrake = "ENGAGED";
                  brakecolor = Colors.redAccent;
                });
              }
              if (value?.elementAt(0) == 187 &&
                  value?.elementAt(2) == 27 &&
                  value?.elementAt(3) == 255) {
                setState(() {
                  pbrake = "-----";
                  brakecolor = Colors.black;
                });

              }
              if (value?.elementAt(0) == 187 &&
                  value?.elementAt(2) == 26) {
                List<int> chunk = <int>[];
                chunk.addAll(value.sublist(3, 7));
                if (chunk.contains(1) || chunk.contains(2) ||
                    chunk.contains(4) || chunk.contains(5)) {
                  setState(() {
                    lamp = "CAUTION";
                    lampcolor = Colors.redAccent;
                  });

                }
                else {
                  if (chunk.contains(0)) {
                    setState(() {
                      lamp = "-----";
                      lampcolor = Colors.black;
                    });

                  }
                  else {
                    if (chunk.contains(3)) {
                      setState(() {
                        lamp = "GOOD";
                        lampcolor = Colors.green;
                      });

                    }
                    else {
                      setState(() {
                        lamp = "RECONNECT";
                        lampcolor = Colors.black;
                      });

                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              if (value?.elementAt(0) == 187 &&
                  value?.elementAt(2) == 9) {
                List<int> tempchunk = <int>[];
                tempchunk.addAll(value.sublist(3, 8));
                double total = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < tempchunk.length; i++) {
                  if (tempchunk[i] == 255 || tempchunk[i] == 254) {
                    tempchunk[i] = 0;
                  }
                  else {
                    total += tempchunk[i];
                  }
                }
                if (total != 0) {
                  double per = (total / 500) * 100;
                  setState(() {
                    cargo = per.toString() + "%";
                  });

                }
                else {
                  setState(() {
                    cargo = "---%";
                  });

                }
              }
            }
          });

          await c.setNotifyValue(true);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Whats the largest MTU size your custom device supports?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan 247!

Comment: Is you app running on Android or iOS? Could you check the correct transmission of your data using a generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)?

Comment: Are you reading the characteristic or using notifications?

Comment: i am using notification!! as per characteristic property notify characteristic have almost data rest are just for reading basic info and writing.

Comment: The notification size should increase with the MTU. Could you check your current MTU with `final mtu = await device.mtu.first;` please?

Comment: let me check...

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Its 20 bytes

Comment: So your `requestMTU` did not work. Could you [edit] your question and show us more of your code?

Comment: i requested mtu 512 now its 247 but same 16 bytes arrays are in notification

Comment: await widget.device.requestMtu(512);
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
        final mtu=await widget.device.mtu.first;
        print(mtu);

Comment: just edited the post check again

Comment: The creator of the library also suggests to increase the MTU size: https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/370 Since you are already doing that I'm at the end of my line here.

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan then is this controllers issue or what? just wanted to know the issue

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your devices. I assume your app runs on Android? Which Version of Android? Have you tried nRF Connect to check if the BLE device behaves correctly as suggested earlier?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan controller is not showing in nrfconnect app..!! other devices are shwoing i dont know why..

Comment: Me neither. Please check all devices for your service or characteristic (I believe it's `6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9- 
      e50e24dcca9e`). Maybe the device just shows a different name or no name at all